# What is the maximum number of Eckardt points of a non-singular cubic surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Every non-singular complex projective cubic surface has $27$ lines. An Eckardt point of a cubic surface is a point where three of the lines intersect. The Fermat cubic has $18$ Eckardt points. What is the maximum number of Eckardt points of a non-singular complex projective cubic surface?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585682/does-any-non-singular-cubic-surface-have-any-point-where-four-lines-intersect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Away from characteristic $2$, in particular over complex numbers, $18$ is the maximum. This was proved in characteristic $0$ by Eckardt; see Proposition 4.3.9 in [Huybrechts, *The geometry of cubic hypersurfaces*](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/Notes.pdf) for a more precise statement and a reference. The bound easily follows from the fact that each of the $27$ lines can be incident with at most $2$ Eckardt points. One way to prove this is to first establish a correspondence between Eckardt points and involutions of $\mathbf{P}^3$ that fix the surface (as a set). A version of this is in section 9 of [Dolgachev and Duncan, *Automorphisms of cubic surfaces in positive characteristic*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01167).

In characteristic $2$, the maximum is $45$ (attained by the Fermat cubic over $\mathbb{F}_4$, see eg Lemma 5.3 in the Dolgachev–Duncan paper). Note that this is an "easy" upper bound in the general case because every smooth cubic surface has exactly $45$ *tritangents* (three of the $27$ lines that pairwise intersect).