# Is there a non-singular cubic surface that has a point where four lines intersect?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Every non-singular complex projective cubic surface has $27$ lines. Is there any such non-singular complex projective cubic surface where four, five, or six lines intersect at a point?

[Post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435377/is-there-a-non-singular-cubic-surface-that-has-a-point-where-four-lines-intersec)

Comment: Any smooth cubic surface is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2$ blown up in 6 suitably chosen points, and the 27 lines are the 6 exceptional divisors, the strict transforms of the 15 lines through two of the 6 blown-up points, and the strict transform of the 6 conics through all but one blown up point. So you're reduced to playing around with lines and conics in the plane - can you take it from here?

Comment: If I don't know what "blown up" means (and I don't), this won't help. Also, this question was asked (by me) a few minutes ago on MathOverflow.

Comment: You have given no indication in the question statement whether you know what blown up means or not. Additionally, there are some guidelines about cross-posting between MSE and MO: see [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo/16290#16290). Most importantly, please link between the two questions once you've posted them and please consider waiting a bit between cross-posts next time.

Comment: This question has been answered on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered on MO (https://mathoverflow.net/a/435379/38621):

> No, this is not possible. If $p$ is a smooth point on any surface $S$, and is contained in a line $l$ on $S$, then $l$ is contained in the tangent plane at $p$, call it $T_p$. Now if $S$ is a cubic then it intersects $T_p$ in a cubic curve (with some singularity at $p$, even though $S$ is smooth at $p$); and a cubic curve can contain at most three lines.